# How do I create a fade picture slideshow with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery code below I am trying to use (I know it's not optimized, but I do not think that is the issue; feel free to optimize it though):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cur = 0;
  function slideshow() {
  $("#imgdisp").fadeOut(400);
  if (cur >= 3) {
    cur = 1;
  } else {
    cur++;
  }
  $("#imgdisp").empty().append("<img height='456px' width='691px' id='img' src='slideshow_home/home_"+cur+".jpg'>");
    $("#imgdisp").fadeIn(400);
    setTimeout(slideshow,4000);
  }
  slideshow();
})
```

With the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscodes/slideshow.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="csscodes/slideshow.css">
<div id="imgdisp">
<img height="456px" width="691px" id="img" src="slideshow_home/home_1.jpg">
</div>
</html>
```

What I am trying to create is a slideshow that does the following (in order):

1) fade out current image

2) remove the current image

3) append a new image (called home_2.jpg, and it goes up to home_3.jpg)

4) fade in

5) wait four seconds to repeat with the next image

However, when I try to run this code, it appends the new image before fading out, so the image appears abruptly, fades out, then fades in, and waits four seconds before it repeats.  My questions are:

1) How do I fix this code such that it changes the image while the div is faded out?

2) Is there a way to have the image fade immediately to the next image?

Thanks in advance to everyone who contributes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var cur = 1;
        function slideshow() {
            if (cur >= 3) {
                cur = 1;
            } else {
                cur++;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#imgdisp").fadeOut(400, function(){
                    $("#imgdisp").empty().append("<img height='456px' width='691px' id='img' src='img_"+cur+".jpg'>");
                    $("#imgdisp").fadeIn(400);
                });
                slideshow();
            }, 4000);
        }
        slideshow();
    });
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked this time, thank you very much!  Any idea as to why my code did not work?

Comment: @KevinO: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe it didn't work because the line after `$("#imgdisp").fadeOut(400);` is executed and because you have `.empty()` the `.fadeOut()` can't be seen, you only see the `.fadeIn()`. So what I did was to wait after the fading out is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cur = 0;
    function slideshow() {
        if (cur >= 3) {
            cur = 1;
        } else {
            cur++;
        }
        $("#imgdisp").empty().append("<img height='456px' width='691px' id='img' src='slideshow_home/home_"+cur+".jpg'>");
        $("#imgdisp").fadeIn(400);
        setTimeout(removeCurrent, 4000);
    }

    function removeCurrent(){
        $("#imgdisp").fadeOut(400);
        slideshow();
    }
    slideshow();
});
```

Comment: It still did not work, it has the same problem with changing the image before it fades away.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NivoSlider` a `jQuery` plugin available [here](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: It looks like something I can try out, but it appears that I cannot use it for my site unless I buy a license (the free version does not say I can use it for a site)

Comment: its a freeware you can use it on your site you don't need to buy license for this

Answer (score 0):

on top of dunli some modification can do what you are looking for -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cur = 0;
    function slideshow() {
        if (cur >= 3) {
            cur = 1;
        } else {
            cur++;
        }

        $("#imgdisp").empty().append("<img style='display:none' src='image_path/home_"+cur+".jpg' />");
        $("#imgdisp img").fadeIn(400);
        setTimeout(removeCurrent, 4000);
    }

    function removeCurrent(){
        $("#imgdisp img").fadeOut(400);
        slideshow();
    }
    slideshow();
});
```

Comment: It still did not work, I added in the src along with the width and height attributes, but it does not even display the image