# Is there a better way to repeat a function, rather than using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to repeat a function infinite times?

Rather than using:

```
    setTimeout(myfunction(), 10)
```

How would I add that into this? When I replaced setTimeout it went weird with the order.

```
    <img id="slideshow" src="4.JPG" alt="cheese" width="264" height="264"/>
            <script>
                source=["1.jpg", "2.JPG", "3.JPG", "4.JPG"];
                var i=0
                function show(){
                document.getElementById("slideshow").src = source[i];
                if (i<source.length - 1)                
                i++
                else
                i=0
                setTimeout("show()",2500)                       
                }
                show()
            </script>
```

Comment: why would you want to repeat a function **infinite** times?

Comment: If you're doing a slideshow of images, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14226290/1953933) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `window.setInterval(function, 1000);`

Comment: when I added that the function executed differently

Comment: @Mikey That will make the function named `function` execute every 1,000 milliseconds (1 second).

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){

  var images = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'],
      img = document.getElementById('blerg');

  setInterval(function(){

    img.src = images[0];

    images.push(images.shift());

  }, 2500)

})();
```

Answer (score -1):

or `while(true) hangTheBrowser();`

Comment: Downvoting because this is pretty much never the right solution.